# Stop the main thread until all task done in a ThreadPoolExecutor - Python DJANGO

Tags: python, django, threadpool

I've some rather heavy stored procedures in a view and I wanted to use threads to execute those queries in parallel but I don't know how to stop the main thread until those queries have finished.

My code:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def resultados(request):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor() 
    context = {}
    executor.submit(resultados_proceso, regiones, territorios, canales, marcas, periodos)
    executor.submit(resultadosGrafica_proceso,regiones, territorios, canales, marcas, periodos)
    executor.submit(get_volumen_ejecucion_clientes_iniciativa, 106)
    executor.submit(get_volumenAP_xmarca, ['M'])

return render(request, 'resultados.html', context)

def resultados_proceso(context, regiones, territorios, canales, marcas, periodos):
    context['resultados'] = getResultados(regiones, territorios, canales, marcas, periodos)

def resultadosGrafica_proceso(context, regiones, territorios, canales, marcas, periodos):
    context['grafica'] = getResultadosGrafica(regiones, territorios, canales, marcas, periodos)
```

Answer (score 1):

did you meant the current request-response thread ?

IIRC, you can call the 'result' method.

So,

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    future1 = executor.submit(do_something, 1.7)
    future2 = executor.submit(do_something_2, 1.7)

    future1.result()
    future2.result()  # will block current thread
```

Hopes it help a bit.

P.S -
i will also tried to explore about the async libraries which can wait to a result without blocking.